# A way around LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, iqueryable

I've got a method I've been using against IEnumerable no problem. However I want to start using it against IQueryable as well. However, the way I currently have it wont work as its trying to execute my method against the database.

The situation is as follows. I want a property on the object I'm selecting into to be be null if the value selecting from is null or the Id and Name of the property if it exists. For example:

```
var foos = FooRepository.All().Select(s => new FooBrief()
{
    Id = s.Id,
    Customer = SimpleData.To(s.Customer, m => m.Id, m => m.Name)
});
```

where `SimpleData.To` looks like:

```
public class SimpleData
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public static SimpleData To<T>(T t, Func<T, int> id, Func<T, string> name) where T : class
    {
        if (t != null)
        {
            return new SimpleData { Id = id(t), Name = name(t) };
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Is there someway I can get this behaviour whilst allowing it to execute against the database?

**NOTE: Because of reasons elsewhere in my code I cannot use .ToList(). I may be adding additional filtering at a later point**

Comment: Can you use `ToArray`? :-) And the reasons why you can't might be relevant.

Comment: The reasons I can't is that I may need to add additional clauses to the iqueryable after this point. So I still want it to execute against the database

Comment: There relevant information on this post ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17187395/using-my-own-method-with-linq-to-entities

Answer (score 2):

The simplest approach is just to perform the selection *outside* the database, using `AsEnumerable`:

```
var foos = FooRepository.All()
                        .Select(x => new { Id = x.Id,
                                           CustomerId = x.Customer.Id,
                                           CustomerName = x.Name })
                        .AsEnumerable()
                        .Select(s => new FooBrief {
                                   Id = s.Id,
                                   Customer = new SimpleData { 
                                       Id = s.CustomerId,
                                       Name = s.CustomerName
                                   }
                                });
```

The first `Select` is just to make sure that the database query only pulls out the required fields. If you really still want to use your `SimpleData.To` method:

```
// Outdented to avoid scrolling
var foos = FooRepository.All()
    .Select(x => new { Id = x.Id,
                       CustomerId = x.Customer.Id,
                       CustomerName = x.Name })
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Select(s => new FooBrief {
               Id = s.Id,
               Customer = SimpleData.To(s,
                                        s => s.CustomerId,
                                        s => s.CustomerName)
            });
```

Comment: The problem I have, which I don't think I made clear. Is that I may be adding addition filtering after this query (A where clause for example) after this point.

Comment: @mjmcloug: Well why not add it *before* this point? Basically you can't execute a custom .NET method while you're still in the EF part of things... at least in general. (I believe there are ways of mapping simple methods to stored procs, but it wouldn't help in your case.) You need to accept that and design appropriately.

Comment: Agreed. I assumed the worst when asking this question but I was curious to see if there was a clever way around it that I wasn't aware of. Before isn't an option at the moment I'm afraid. I'll have to have a think about this one

Comment: @mjmcloug: Note that with the *first* form you may be able to add `Where` clauses afterwards... but definitely not the second.