# Get array of string from variable using linq

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

```
var tskStatus = from task in vpnTaskQuery
                join groupname in dbContext.vpn_groupname on task.taskName equals groupname.TASK_NAME
                select new
                {
                    taskName = task.taskName,
                    groupName = groupname.Functional_Group,
                    taskStatus = getStatus(task.TaskStatus),
                    Seq = addSequence(groupname.Functional_Group)
                } into newTask
                orderby newTask.Seq ascending
                select newTask;

string[] groupName = tskStatus.Select(s => s.groupName)
                              .Distinct()
                              .ToArray<string>();
```

//this is the code for my getStatus
 private object getStatus(string pStatus)
        {
            string retStatus = string.Empty;
            switch (pStatus)
            {
                case "I_ASSIGNED":
                    retStatus = "Pending";
                    break;
                case "I_AVAILABLE":
                    retStatus = "Pending";
                    break;
                case "I_COMPLETED":
                    retStatus = "Completed";
                    break;
                case "System Delayed":
                    retStatus = "Pending";
                    break;
                case "Hibernated":
                    retStatus = "Pending";
                    break;
                default:
                    retStatus = "Pending";
                    break;
            }
            return retStatus;
        }
    }

Comment: when I try to get array of group name got runtime error, linq to entities does  not recognoize the method system.object.getstatus

Comment: Perfectly understandable, I don't recognize it either. What is it?

Comment: I need get array of groupname from tskStatus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that you can't use the `getStatus()`, is because LINQ To Entities converts a LINQ query to SQL, and LINQ To Entities can't convert the `getStatus()` method to SQL.

Comment: In getStatus, just try to replace task.status string into another string

Comment: how to replace those value in select statement

Comment: @user3129983: Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17187395/2619912