# Custom method in IQueryable<T>.Select

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, iqueryable

I need to run custom method in `IQueryable<T>.Select` statement, e.g.

```
query.Select(r => new ResultObject()
{
Id = r.Persion.Id,
Code = r.Person.Code,
CalculatedField = CalculateField(r.Person)
}
```

Problem is, I can't run it like this, as linq-to-sql exception is thrown. CalculateField is basically a switch statement:

```
private static CalcFieldEnum CalculateField(Person p)
{
    if(p.Age < 21)
    {
         if(p.Salary > 2000 && p.YearsWorked > 2)
             return CalcFieldEnum.TypeB;
         else if(p.YearsWorked <= 2)
             return CalcFieldEnum.TypeC;
    }
    else
    {
        if(p.Salary > 3000)
            return CalcFieldEnum.TypeB;
    }

    return CalcFieldEnum.TypeA;
}
```

The only thing that matters about the method (CalculateField) is that it just takes some entity and returns result based on entity's field values.

I can't run this method post-query, as user can sort results by columns, and sorting run on IQueryable as well. Is there any way I can solve this?

**P.S** I simplified the method's logic, in reality there are *a lot* more of those if-else statements. The idea is the same, though - it just returns an enum value based on object's fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `AsEnumerable` method to fetch and load records from DB then use whatever method you want:

```
query.AsEnumerable().Select(...);
```

Comment: Great, there will be some sorting problems (sort by field name), but those are solvable. My main concern is performance - would there be any performance hit by executing sorting locally?

Comment: It depends on how many records you have in db. In situations like this I usually do the filtering in DB, fetch the results and perform other _unsupported_ operations in memory. in your case I think it shouldn't matter too much. you will eventually fetch the records anyway

Answer (score 2):

If you can rewrite the method as an lambda, e.g.

```
p => p.Age < 21
    ? (
        (p.Salary > 2000 && p.YearsWorked > 2)
            ? CalcFieldEnum.TypeB
            : (p.YearsWorked <= 2 ? CalcFieldEnum.TypeC : CalcFieldEnum.TypeA)
      )
    : ( p.Salary > 3000 ? CalcFieldEnum.TypeB : CalcFieldEnum.TypeA);
```

then you should be able to pass it to the database.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mention that if-else statement is quite long so rewriting it with ternary operator produces an unreadable mess.

Comment: @Arnthor Well, it's a tossup between an unreadable mess and executing it (and the subsequent sort) locally, then.

Comment: So you'd advice against sorting locally, on big sets?

Comment: ... Yes? :D The database should be much better at that

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is not supported and honestly it's not supposed to be possible to translate every custom C# method into SQL statements. Take a look at:

[Using my own method with LINQ to Entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17187395/using-my-own-method-with-linq-to-entities)

and

http://forums.asp.net/t/1858815.aspx?LINQ+to+Entities+does+not+recognize+the+method+exception+when+using+custom+extension+method