# Split number from string for order by clause in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I have string column contains 1st Batch, 2nd Batch, 10th Batch etc. Now I am trying to sort them using this string field on ascending order e.g. 1, 2, 3 but having no luck.

```
public ActionResult PublicGrid()
{
    ViewBag.members = db.Members.Count().ToString();    

    return View(db.Members.OrderBy(a => Regex.Replace(a.Batch, @"[^\d]", String.Empty)).ThenBy(a=> a.LastName).ToList());
}
```

I have tried the above reg expression but getting error -

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String Replace(System.String, System.String, System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

I have tried this Linq expression but still, throws error -

```
var members = (from m in db.Members
                      orderby Char.IsDigit(Convert.ToChar(m.Batch)) ascending
                      select m).ToList();
```

I have tried creating a static function to split the string like below but still not working.

```
public ActionResult PublicGrid()
{
    ViewBag.members = db.Members.Count().ToString();

    return View(db.Members.OrderBy(a => NumberOnly((a.Batch))).ThenBy(a=> a.LastName).ToList());
}

public static string NumberOnly(string strRaw)
{
    string numbers = string.Empty;

    foreach (char c in strRaw)
    {            
        if (Char.IsNumber(c))
        {
            numbers += c;
        }
    }
    return numbers;
}
```

Any help much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Someone mentioned this question is similar to previously asked questions but I could not find any similarity.

Comment: You would first need to materialize the query to memory (e.g. `db.Members.ToList().....` since `Regex.Replace()` cannot be converted to SQL

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String Format(System.String, System.Object, System.Object)'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10079990/linq-to-entities-does-not-recognize-the-method-system-string-formatsystem-stri)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using my own method with LINQ to Entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17187395/using-my-own-method-with-linq-to-entities)

Comment: Can you provide some examples for what *real* `Batch` values look like? I think you "might" be able to solve this within the query if `Batch` values always follow a structured pattern

Comment: @AndrésRobinet Batch values are - 1st Batch, 2nd Batch, 3rd Batch ...38th Batch

Comment: @Tajuddin There are ordinal numbers pattern, you can check the last digit & possible using switch statement (what you're want to: convert to number or convert to string ordinals?).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Stephen for pointing the light on my issue. I have to materialize the dataset first then apply the sorting condition. I have changed my code and it seems to be sorting correctly after the change. Here is my code in case if someone faces the similar issue -

```
public ActionResult PublicGrid()
    {
        ViewBag.members = db.Members.Count().ToString();

        var members = db.Members.ToList();

        return View(members.OrderBy(a => NumberOnly((a.Batch))).ThenBy(a=> a.LastName).ToList());

    }

    public static int NumberOnly(string strRaw)
    {

        string numbers = string.Empty;

        foreach (char c in strRaw)
        {

            if (Char.IsNumber(c))
            {
                numbers += c;
            }
        }

        return Int32.Parse(numbers);
    }
```

Comment: this code will fail if there is a number after batches. Try putting a condition to end the loop when Char.IsNumber returns false. Also put another condition if number is empty string return something useful maybe 0 so it comes on top of the order by query

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer:** I didn't try it with a real EF model and context. But both `Substring` and `Length` are supported by query providers

Also, if you are going to do `Skip` and `Take` after the `OrderBy`, it may be better to let the SQL engine deal with it... otherwise you have to materialize ALL results to sort in memory (just a blind guess)

Notice that this works because I'm assuming suffix has a fixed length (which is the only interesting part about the suffix... one could as well just declare `suffixLength = 8`)

```
var batchSuffix = "xx Batch";

// Use db.Members instead of this
var query = new List<Member>
{
    new Member("1st Batch"), new Member("2nd Batch"), new Member("3rd Batch"), new Member("38th Batch"),
    new Member("12nd Batch"), new Member("23rd Batch"), new Member("324th Batch"), new Member("32th Batch")
}.AsQueryable();

var result = query
    .Select(m => new
    {
        Member = m,
        BatchNumber =  m.Batch.Substring(0, m.Batch.Length - batchSuffix.Length)
    })
    .OrderBy(m => m.BatchNumber.Length)
    .ThenBy(m => m.BatchNumber)
    .Select(m => m.Member)
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

While your solution may work, I see some room for improvement:

**NumberOnly**

- `char.IsNumber` checks for a unicode category which contains more characters than '0'..'9', so parsing may fail in general.
- If the first character is not a number, you parse an empty string -> exception.
- Building a string character by character just to parse it as an int is inefficient.
- Would prefer to name it to something more specific.

What about this?

```
private static int IntPrefix(string s) => s
    .TakeWhile(ch => ch >= '0' && ch <= '9')
    .Aggregate(0, (a, c) => 10 * a + (c - '0'));
```

**member ordering**

- You materialize a list, then enumerate that list for sorting (which internally has to also materialize it), then build another list; we see way too many `.ToList()`s on here.
- The `NumberOnly` may be called many times on a single entity during the sort; better to precalculate that.

The sorted list can be expressed like this:

```
db.Members
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Select(m => new { Member = m, BatchNo = IntPrefix(m.Batch) })
    .OrderBy(mb => mb.BatchNo)
    .ThenBy(mb => mb.Member.LastName)
    .Select(mb => mb.Member)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: I have tried your solution but it does not sort the records as I wanted. Thanks anyway for your help.

Comment: Could you please give an example input that does not sort as you want, along with the desired correct result?